# CakePHP: Erro Upload

Tags: php, cakephp

Não estou conseguindo mover as minhas imagens e muito menos detectar o erro no código, e não está sendo exibida mensagens de erro na tela

Meu Model Photo:

```
public $validate = array(
        'uploadImg' => array(
                'uploadError' => array(
                    'rule' => 'uploadError',
                    'message' => 'Fail.',
                    'allowEmpty' => TRUE,
                ),
                'mineType' => array(
                    'rule' => array('mineType',array('image/gif','image/png','image/jpg','image/jpeg')),
                    'message' => 'JUST (GIF,PNG e JPG).',
                    'allowEmpty' =>TRUE,
                ),
                'fileSize' => array(
                        'rule' => array(
                            'fileSize', '<=', '1MB'
                        ),
                        'message' => 'Photos < 1MB',
                        'allowEmpty' => TRUE
                    ),
                'processCoverUpload' => array(
                        'rule' => 'processCoverUpload',
                        'message' => 'Cover Image Upload'
                    ),
            ),
    );

public function processCoverUpload($check = array()){
    if(!is_uploaded_file($check['uploadImg']['tmp_name'])){
        return FALSE;
    }
    if(!move_uploaded_file($check['uploadImg']['tmp_name'], WWW_ROT.'img'.DS.'uploads'.DS.$check['uploadImg']['name'])){
        return FALSE;
    }
    $this->data[$this->alias]['uploadImg'] = 'uploads'.DS.$check['uploads']['name'];
        return TRUE;
}
```

Meu Controller

```
public function add(){
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            $this->Photo->create();
            $data = $this->request->data['Photo'];
            $this->Photo->processCoverUpload($data);
            //debug($this->request);
            if(!$data['uploadImg']['name']){
                unset($data['uploadImg']);
            }

            if($this->Photo->save($data)){
                $this->Session->setFlash(_('Imagem salva'));                
                return $this->redirect(array('controller'=> 'home', 'action' => 'index'));
            }else{
                $this->Session->setFlash(_('Não conseguimos salvar'));
            }
        }       
    }
```

E meu formulario:

```
<?php  print $this->Form->create('Photo', array('action'=>'add', 'type' => 'file'));  ?>
    <fieldset>      
        <legend>Upload</legend>
        <?php print $this->Form->input('Image:', array('type' => 'file', 'name' => 'uploadImg')); ?>        
    </fieldset>
        <?php print $this->Form->end(_("Save")); ?>
```

Depurando o array para ver se está vindo o tmp não encontrei nada estranho pelo que me parece

```
'form' => array( 'uploadImg' => array( 
'name' => '1503852_509064475876526_1876445108_n.jpg', 
'type' => 'image/jpeg', 
'tmp_name' => 'C:\Program Files (x86)\xamp\tmp\php5AA.tmp', 
'error' => (int) 0, 'size' => (int) 8411 ) )
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar, não estou conseguindo identificar o problema, e estou aprendendo a usar o cake.

@Edit: 
  Bom, alguns testes que fiz, percebo que talvez aja um erro dentro minha primeira clausula do IF na função processCoverUpload, ele ta caindo no return, mas como eu já tinha identificado qual é o tipo de dado que esta vindo o meu array, como está acima, 'tmp_name' parece estar certo não?

Comment: Ative o modo de depuração do framework para encontrar pistas de logs de erros. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/debugging.html

Answer (score 1):

Olá, não sou especialista em cakePHP, mas pode ser um erro de digitação entre: mimeType e mineType, onde o correto seria: mimeType.

Altere o seu array $validate no Model Photo da seguinte forma

```
public $validate = array(
    'uploadImg' => array(
            'uploadError' => array(
                'rule' => 'uploadError',
                'message' => 'Fail.',
                'allowEmpty' => TRUE,
            ),
            'mimeType' => array(
                'rule' => array('mimeType',array('image/gif','image/png','image/jpg','image/jpeg')),
                'message' => 'JUST (GIF,PNG e JPG).',
                'allowEmpty' =>TRUE,
            ),
            'fileSize' => array(
                    'rule' => array(
                        'fileSize', '<=', '1MB'
                    ),
                    'message' => 'Photos < 1MB',
                    'allowEmpty' => TRUE
                ),
            'processCoverUpload' => array(
                    'rule' => 'processCoverUpload',
                    'message' => 'Cover Image Upload'
                ),
        ),
);
```

Comment: Editado @Andrey

Comment: Melhor agora =)

Comment: Excelente percepção :) eu agradeço, corrigi mas ainda não consigo mover o arquivo! Vou dar um update com um pouco mais de detalhes

Comment: O arquivo chega a ser criado na pasta temporária?